# How can I make an event when theme change

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, ace-editor

When theme change, I want to make a event. not use `setTheme()`.

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
ace.require("ace/ext/settings_menu").init(editor);
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/java");
editor.setOptions({
    theme: "ace/theme/tomorrow_night_bright"
});

editor.on('changeTheme', function() {    -> This is not working
    console.log(editor.mode)
})
```

I try to changeTheme event, and I use `$("#-theme").change()` event but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are themeChange and themeLoaded events on `editor.renderer` see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/31bbd6ade094c1e142565837a4ee93c7931399a4/src/virtual_renderer.js#L1721

```
editor.renderer.on('themeChange', function() {
    // theme setting changed
})
editor.renderer.on('themeLoaded', function() {
    // theme loaded and applied to editor
})
```